# Записать несколько результатов поиска в разные переменные - PHP

Tags: php

Вот скрипт:

```
 <?php
    $host='localhost'; // имя хоста (уточняется у провайдера)
    $database='db'; // имя базы данных, которую вы должны создать
    $user='user'; // заданное вами имя пользователя, либо определенное провайдером
    $pswd=''; // заданный вами пароль

    $dbh = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pswd) or die("Не могу соединиться с MySQL.");
    mysql_select_db($database) or die("Не могу подключиться к базе.");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $query = "SELECT opisanie FROM `db` where tema='тема'";
    $res =  mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($res);
    echo $row[0];
    ?>
```

Допустим, у нас нашлось несколько результатов по ключу "тема", в какой переменной находится первый и второй результаты?
P.S. $row[1] пробовал, не помогло.

Странно. Если написать `$query = "SELECT * FROM db where tema='тема' limit 0,2";`, то вывод происход нормально (но выводится не та информация, которая мне нужна), если же написать `$query = "SELECT opisanie FROM db where tema='тема' limit 0,2";`, то возникает ошибка: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT `opisanie` FROM `db` where tema='тема';") or die(mysql_error());
echo '<pre>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($res))
  print_r($row);
echo '</pre>';
```

Привыкайте уже к нормальному коду.

*PS: Обращение к полю объекта: `$row->opisanie`*

*PPS: вы запрашиваете* **одно** *поле, поэтому вам доступно только `$row[0]`. Выбрать все поля - запрос "`SELECT * FROM ...`"*

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно перебирать в цыкле:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
    echo $row[0];
}
```

А чтобы получить две строки, пишем такой заапрос:

```
$query = "SELECT opisanie FROM `db` where tema='тема' limit 0,2";
```

Comment: А как получить все строки, где найден ключ?

Comment: И там ошибка получается: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in...

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `db` where tema='тема'";

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
    echo $row[0]." - ".$row[1];
}
```

Попробуй сделать полную выборку и посмотри поля, может ты ошибся где?

Comment: Странно. Если написать <code>$query = "SELECT * FROM `db` where tema='тема' limit 0,2";</code>, то вывод происход нормально (но выводится не та информация, которая мне нужна), если же написать <code>$query = "SELECT opisanie FROM `db` where tema='тема' limit 0,2";</code>, то возникает ошибка: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in...

Comment: попробуй написать так 

$query = "SELECT `opisanie` FROM `db` where tema='тема' limit 0,2";

Кавычки мускуловские подставь, это как один из вариантов решения, иногда помогает.

Comment: Понял, такие одинарные перекошенные кавычки. Подставил. Не помогло...

Comment: Подсчитал кол-во вхождений слова, которое ищу, сделал одновременный вывод этого числа и информации из таблицы opisanie. Пишет 2 вхождения, странно, что все равно ошибка выводится...